# How to make correct syntax for XQuery Looping

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

Now I have a dita composite like:

```
<root>
 <topic>....</topic>
 <topic>....</topic>
 <topic>....</topic>
 <topic>....</topic>
 <topic>....</topic>
</root>
```

And I simply need to write an xquery that basically will create a ditamap for each topic, so the resutling ditamap should look like:

```
<map>
 <topicref>....</topicref>
 <topicref>....</topicref>
 <topicref>....</topicref>
 <topicref>....</topicref>
 <topicref>....</topicref>
</map>
```

My current Xquery isn't quite doing the right thing, it is able to catch each topic, but instead of creating one ditamp, it creates multiple ditamap, one for each topic:

```
 $isFoSaved := for $b in $mapNode/*[local-name() = 'topic']
               let                                     
               $topicWithPI := let $holder:=1
               return (
                      <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" navtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic"/>
                ),
```

Could experts help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only see that you are embedding multiple flwor expressions.

Whenever you use `$x := let $y ...` or `$x := for $y ...` you start a new flwor expression which must be closed by a `return` clause. Therefore, your code snipped is invalid/incomplete: You have two opened flwor expressions, but only one `return` clause.

If you try to keep it flat it will be much easier.

For example:

```
<map>{
 let $mapNode := 
   <root>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
    </root>
  for $b in $mapNode/*[local-name() = 'topic']
  return 
    <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" 
              avtitle="Begin"
              scope="local" 
              type="topic"/>
}</map>
```

this query works on [try.zorba-xquery.com](http://try.zorba-xquery.com/), but I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. Can I ask you more, what if we have nested topics(i.e, topic within topic), are we able to capture that in xquery?

Comment: Of course, that is what XQuery/XPath is best in. If you just use $mapNode//*[local-name() = 'topic'] (double shlashes) you will get topicrefs for all decendents as well. If you'd like to preserve the hierarchy it is a little bit more complex: See other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to preserve the hierarchy of nested topics it is a little bit more complex. I think it is best to use a recursive function for this:

```
declare function local:topicref($topics)
{
  for $b in $topics
  return 
    <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" 
              avtitle="Begin"
              scope="local" 
              type="topic">{
      local:topicref($b/*[local-name() = 'topic'])
    }</topicref>

};

<map>{
 let $mapNode := 
   <root>
     <topic><topic>....</topic></topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
     <topic>....</topic>
    </root>
 return 
   local:topicref(
     $mapNode/*[local-name() = 'topic']
   )
}</map>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
  <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" avtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic">
    <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" avtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic"/>   
  </topicref>
  <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" avtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic"/>
  <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" avtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic"/>
  <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" avtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic"/>
  <topicref href="1.xml#Begin" avtitle="Begin" scope="local" type="topic"/>
</map>
```